# Can this cursor be replaced

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, cursor, sql-server-2012

I am currently using a cursor in my sql server procedure. Wanted to know if there is anyway to replace it with a better approach. Process is

1. Customer pays some money, and I create an entry for it in the payment table.
2. I start a cursor that selects all payments of that customer that have an available balance, from PAYMENT TABLE
3. Then I start an inner cursor that fetches all the bills of that customer which are still unpaid, from BILL TABLE
4. I pay off each bill till the current payment is exhausted and then repeat the process

How can I remove the cursors for a more effective way in steps 2 and 3. Also does use of cursors mean that the PAYMENT and BILL tables remain locked till the procedure runs?

Tx

Comment: You can definitely use a set based approach for this.  If you want specific help you need to share your table structure and existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way it can be done, with made up tables and data since we don't know what yours look like. I'm putting some narrative in in places but all of the code should be run as one single script.

Data setup:

```
declare @bills table (billid int, balance decimal(38,4))
declare @payments table (paymentid int, balance decimal(38,4))

insert into @bills (billid, balance) values
(1,0), (2,22.50), (3,12.75), (4,19.20)
insert into @payments (paymentid,balance) values
(1,20.19),(2,5.50),(3,20)

declare @newpayments table (billid int, paymentid int,
                            paymentamount decimal(38,4))
```

I've assumed that the `bills` and `payments` tables have a column, called `balance` which shows any amounts not dealt with as yet. Alternatively, you may have to calculate this from a couple of columns. But no sample data in your question means I get to make up an easy structure :-)

Query to populate `@newpayments` with which bills should be paid from which (partial) payments<sup>1</sup>:

```
; With unpaidbills as (
    select billid,balance,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY billid) as rn,
        SUM(balance) OVER (ORDER BY billid
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                           AND CURRENT ROW) as endbalance,
        SUM(balance) OVER (ORDER BY billid
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                           AND CURRENT ROW) - balance as startbalance
    from @bills
    where balance > 0
), unusedpayments as (
    select paymentid,balance,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY paymentid) as rn,
        SUM(balance) OVER (ORDER BY paymentid
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                           AND CURRENT ROW) as endbalance,
        SUM(balance) OVER (ORDER BY paymentid
                      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                           AND CURRENT ROW) - balance as startbalance
    from @payments
    where balance > 0
), overlaps as (
    select
        billid,paymentid,
        CASE WHEN ub.startbalance < up.startbalance
                THEN up.startbalance ELSE ub.startbalance END as overlapstart,
        CASE WHEN ub.endbalance > up.endbalance
                THEN up.endbalance ELSE ub.endbalance END as overlapend
    from
        unpaidbills ub
            inner join
        unusedpayments up
            on
                ub.startbalance < up.endbalance and
                up.startbalance < ub.endbalance
)
insert into @newpayments(billid,paymentid,paymentamount)
select billid,paymentid,overlapend - overlapstart as paymentamount
from overlaps
```

At this point, `@newpayments` can be used to generate transaction history, etc

And then, finally we update the original tables to mark the amounts used:

```
;With totalpaid as (
    select billid,SUM(paymentamount) as payment from @newpayments
    group by billid
)
update b
set b.balance = b.balance - tp.payment
from @bills b
    inner join
    totalpaid tp
    on b.billid = tp.billid

;With totalused as (
    select paymentid,SUM(paymentamount) as payment from @newpayments
    group by paymentid
)
update p
set p.balance = p.balance - tu.payment
from @payments p
    inner join
    totalused tu
    on p.paymentid = tu.paymentid
```

The key part was to use `SUM()` with [window functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) to calculate the running totals of the amounts owed (bills) or amounts available (payments), in both cases using a column (billid or paymentid) to determine in what order each of these items should be dealt with. E.g. the `unpaidbills` CTE produces a result set like this:

```
billid      balance   rn                   endbalance    startbalance
----------- --------- -------------------- ------------- -------------
2           22.5000   1                    22.5000       0.0000
3           12.7500   2                    35.2500       22.5000
4           19.2000   3                    54.4500       35.2500
```

and `unusedpayments` looks like this:

```
paymentid   balance    rn                   endbalance   startbalance
----------- ---------- -------------------- ------------ -------------
1           20.1900    1                    20.1900      0.0000
2           5.5000     2                    25.6900      20.1900
3           20.0000    3                    45.6900      25.6900
```

We then create the `overlaps` CTE which finds overlaps<sup>2</sup> between the bills and payments where (part of) a payment can be used to satisfy (part of) a bill. The region of the overlap is the actual amount to pay for that bill.

---

<sup>1</sup> The `ROW_NUMBER()` calls aren't really needed. In an early part of writing this query, I thought I was going to use these but it turned out to be unnecessary. But removing them doesn't shorten things enough to allow SO to stop scrolling that query anyway, and so I may as well leave them in (and not have to edit the result sets shown lower down also)

<sup>2</sup> Many people trying to find overlaps make things absurdly complicated and deal with many special cases to find all overlaps. This can usually be done far more simply in the way that I show in the `overlaps` CTE - two ranges overlap if the first range *starts* before the second range *ends*, **and** the second range *starts* before the first range *ends*.

The only tricky thing to do is to decide whether you want to deal with two ranges that abut (the first one's end value is exactly equal to the second one's start or vice versa) but that just leads to a decision on whether to use `<` or `<=` in the comparisons.

In this instance, we don't care if a payment exactly paid off the *previous* bill so we use `<` to avoid treating such situations as an overlap.